# How to change the condition operator in the search api query?

Tags: views, 8, search

I have a date field facet filter on my search api views page.

When I select a date in the filter, the search api display those results which has that date value selected in the date field.

I want to display those results which has a date value which is greater than or equal to the selected in the date facet filter.

Is it possible? I checked with the search api query alter hook but I can't see any helpful function to alter the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overridden these classes in my custom module

```
Drupal\facets\Plugin\facets\query_type\SearchApiDate;
Drupal\facets\QueryType\QueryTypeRangeBase;
```

And then modified this function

```
public function execute()
```

of `QueryTypeRangeBase` and used the correct operator.